# Как получить ответ HTML с методом POST формы с помощью php?

Tags: php, парсер, curl, dom

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как получить элемент с ценой HTML DOM с [сайта](http://www.k-rauta.ru/).

Мне требуется получать цену товара с сайта по url страницы с этим товаром. Вот одна из таких страниц - [Страница для парсинга](http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx?pid=000000000501204050)

На странице имеется HTML форма с методом POST, которая получает информацию о товаре. Как получить данные с ценой из этой HTML формы с удаленного сервера, с помощью php и cURL, я понятия не имею.

Мне подойдет решение на php с cURL, или с решение через какую-нибудь php библиотеку, или любое другое решение, которое можно применить на сервер под Linux.

**Для решения моей задачи требовалось передать куки сессии. Подробнее [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34295757/how-to-get-the-response-of-form-with-post-method-by-curl/34298449?noredirect=1).**

Answer (score 1):

Можете воспользоваться например банальным `file_get_contents` а потом работать с дом моделью используя библиотеку например [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/)
или похожие, коих достаточно написано.

Comment: Попробуйте "ссылку для парсинга" передать file_get_contents() и посмотреть результат. У меня не выходит.

Comment: где тестируете? на сервере? локально? получение по сети может не работать из за настроек php.ini

Comment: у вас ссылка не валидная какая то, откуда в ней скобки...

Comment: _Сообщение об ошибке

службы непредвиденная ошибка и поступил на службу журнала.

Приносим свои извинения за эту ситуацию.

k-rauta.ru_

Comment: Парсер под виндой на OpenServer (локально), сайт на удаленном хосте. Ссылку я использую из адресной строки браузера.

Comment: у меня по этой ссылке получается страница с ошибкой от сайта с которого пытаюсь получить страницу через `file_get_contents`

Comment: С ошибкой я тоже получаю. Я не могу разобраться, как по этой ссылке получить HTML DOM соотвествующей страницы, а не ошибку.

Comment: даже при попытке получить url http://www.k-rauta.ru/pages/product.aspx Выходит та же ошибка, у них защита стоит от парсинга.

Comment: наверное придется через cURL и в нем указывать заголовки и т.д. прикидываясь браузером.

Comment: Я сомневаюсь что это защита. Через cURL я получал главную страницу, вернее HTML DOM главной страницы. Страницу товара мне не получить.

Comment: Урл кривой имхо.

Comment: Я не силен в cURL. Мне сложно написать такой скрипт.

Comment: Добавьте ваш код получения курлом страницы в вопрос.

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавил.

Comment: попробуйте открыть ваш урл в браузере, скопируйте его и попробуйте открыть, у меня по нему нет никаких товаров, а идет редирект на страницу http://www.k-rauta.ru/shops/pages/storeselection.aspx

Comment: Я исправил url. Сайту достаточно передать один параметр - pid с айди товара. Сайт использует этот параметр в HTML форме, чтобы получить товар на странице. У формы, стати метод POST.